# Can't Access a file I downloaded since I don't have permissions yet I am admin?

Tags: windows-7, windows, 64-bit

I downloaded some file and everytime I try to copy it or move it somewhere I get these errors

> Windows cannot access the specified
>   device, path , or file. You may not
>   have the appropriate permissions to
>   access the item.
>
> You need permission to perform this
>   action You require permission from
>   "user(where this is my pc
>   name/myusername)" to make changes to
>   this file.

Yet I am an admin and it is my only account on this computer and it saying to me I need permissions to open it up from "chobo2" user yet that's the account I am logged in as.

I don't get it. How do I disable this stupid message so I can access every file I want.

I am using windows 7 ultimate 64bit.

As far as I know I have full permissions set so I don't know why I am getting this.

Comment: What is the file and do you have Microsoft Security Essentials installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check file/containing folder permissions and ownership. There should be something wrong with them. This message is typical if you tried to play with them before and messed settings up. If you are the owner than you can override security settings to allow you do whatever, otherwise you'll have to force-override the owner first.

Check out [this article](http://www.blogsdna.com/2159/how-to-take-ownership-grant-permissions-to-access-files-folder-in-windows-7.htm). It has some pretty images and step-by-step tutorials.