# How to remove ReadOnly from files in Windows 7?

Tags: windows, windows-7, permissions, read-only

I am using Windows 7 and want to remove readonly from files, I tried all possible method like unchecking the readonly option from properties... using attrib command in CMD and 
Right-click on "My computer" > Select "Manage" > Under "System Tools" you'll find "Shared Folders" expand and select "Shares"> in here select the Share Name of your data (where the Read Only access is), and double-click it. > click on the tab "Share Permissions" and verify the correct group (individual) has “full control”.

I am still unable to remove it.... Any suggestion?

Comment: What went wrong when you tried those things?

Comment: file still remains read only... the read only tab is still checked

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to delete a file protected by Windows](http://superuser.com/questions/352883/how-to-delete-a-file-protected-by-windows)

Answer (score 3):

Type cmd in the Start Menu or in Run and to...

Remove read-only attribute from a file type:

```
ATTRIB -R "C:\YourFile.ext"
```

Remove read-only attributes from a folder type:

```
ATTRIB -R "C:\YourFolder" /D
```

Remove read-only attributes from a directory tree (and all the files within) type:

```
ATTRIB -R "C:\YourFolder" /S /D
```

Otherwise, it may be an ACL issue and being on Windows 7, you'll want to use ICACLS:

```
ICACLS "C:\YourFileOrFolder" /grant:r %USERNAME%:F
```

You might need to specify your computer's name:

```
ICACLS "C:\YourFileOrFolder" /grant:r %COMPUTERNAME%\%USERNAME%:F
```

And if you need recursion:

```
ICACLS "C:\YourFileOrFolder" /grant:r %COMPUTERNAME%\%USERNAME%:F /T
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a networking problem. I had set the "D" spinner as shared in "Share" tab, for "Everyone". In the "Security" tab, I gave "Everyone" "Full Control" for all folders, sub-folders, and files. Still the files opened up as "Read-only". I then had to right-click each main folder in the drive, and set "Everyone" from the default "read" to "read/write". Then every file was fully shared.

Comment: This is **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).